# Degree of the sum of two scheme morphisms from a curve to $\mathbb P^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, schemes, projective-schemes

Consider two global sections of a same line bundle $\mathcal O(D)$ on a projective, smooth, geometrically connected curve $X$ over a field $k$. They induce two scheme morphisms $f,g:X\longrightarrow\mathbb A^1\longrightarrow \mathbb P^1_k$, sending $k[x]\longrightarrow \mathcal O(D)$, $x\mapsto f$. Now we can take linear combinations of the sections, e.g. $f+g$: this is again a global section and therefore induces a morphism in $\mathbb P^1$.

> What is the degree of the induced map?

I would claim that, if $\rm deg\ f\neq \rm deg\ g$, the degree is the maximum, as happens for polynomials. The problem is that the degree of a map in $\mathbb P^1$ is not the one of the polynomial that induces it…

Remark: I call degree of a scheme morphism $f$ the number $[k(X):k(Y)]$ (seeing the second immersed the first by $f^*$) if $f$ is dominant, $0$ otherwise.

ADDED LATER: With this kind of result I actually hope to prove that, if the global sections of the line bundle contain maps of several degree, then the dimension of the vector space of global sections must be high… Is this true? Does it have any links with the presence of maps of several distinct degrees?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Global sections of what? (A line bundle on $X$?) Note that in general you need two global sections of a line bundle to get a single morphism to $P^1$...

Comment: The only sections that arise that way are constant, because every global section of the structure sheaf on a projective curve is constant. (Another way to say this is that the only maps from a projective curve to affine space are constant.)

Comment: Edited, thanks! The morphism is the one induced in $\mathbb A^1$, composed with the open immersion.

Comment: (Not to give the wrong impression that this is special for curves, this is true for all projective schemes, where constant means the degree 0 part of the graded ring to which we applied the Proj construction.)

Comment: Can you be more clear about how a single global section of a line bundle is supposed to induced a map to affine space. The only natural construction I can think of is not well defined (as you choose different trivializations), I think.

Comment: Of course: edited.

Comment: Again, the only sections of $O_X(X)$ are the constant functions, so the map you define is constant.

Comment: Actually, you are right. I've been told that since $\mathcal O(D)$ is a line bundle (so locally isomorphic to $\mathcal O_X$) then what I am considering defines a scheme morphism (but possibly not trivial since the global sections of the line bundle are not trivial): is this true?

Comment: If $f_0, \ldots, f_n$ are sections of a line bundle $O(D)$, then indeed you can use your local trivializations to define a map to $P^n$. (As you work with different trivializations, the maps defined agree up to scalar, so together they glue to a map to projective space, which is written $[f_0 : \ldots : f_n]$. To learn where it sends a point, you trivialize around that point, which turns the $f_i$ into honest regular functions, and then evaluate. You need to check this is well defined, different sections change the result by a scalar.) For a map to $P^1$, you need 2 sections to do this. .

Comment: Ravi Vakil explains this in his chapter(s) on line bundles and maps to projective space. Highly recommended reading if you want to make sense of this. It's confusing at first. Think about $P^1$ a lot. Good luck.